# Way to export all the data from Cassandra cluster to file(s)

Tags: ruby, cassandra, cqlsh

I need to export Cassandra schema and data to a file in order to quickly setup identical cluster when needed.

**Identical** likely means the same topology, same number of nodes and replication factor.

In case of NetworkTopologyStrategy simple file backup/sstable snapshot is not helpful cause peer IPs are recorded with other data. After restore on another node it tries to reach source cluster seeds.

I was surprised there is almost no ready solution for such task.

Suppose i have to use `DESC SCHEMA;` then parse output for all the tables, backup them with `COPY keyspace.table TO /backup/keyspace.table.csv;` and later use sstableloader to restore on other node.

Any better solutions?

Comment: Actually cause ruby-cassandra-driver doesn't support DESC and COPY I decided to make shellouts to cqlsh.

the instruction from answer below looks too complex for my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the solution you've specified.

Or you can use snapshots option (looks easier for me). Here's a docs describing how to copy snapshots between clusters:

http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/operations/ops_snapshot_restore_new_cluster.html